# Converting a date format into another in Apache Camel

Tags: spring-boot, date, apache-camel

I have defined a header in my camelcontext file which reads the incoming date and sets into another body. But the problem is the incoming date format is dd-mm-yyyy and I have to pass as MM/DD/YYYY.

/* In this header I am setting the incoming date */

```
<setHeader  headerName="fitnessUpto">
                            <simple>${exchangeProperty.fitnessUpto}</simple>
                        </setHeader>
```

/*But in body I have to pass as MM/DD/YYYY format */
<tm:TMRCValidityDate>${header.fitnessUpto}</tm:TMRCValidityDate>

Can you please suggest how to convert the incoming date format into desired Date format using apache camel, also please attach any dependancy required.

Incoming date format, "fitnessUpto":"11-11-2036" and I have set this in myheader. But want to convert this date format into MM/DD/YYYY and set this new format into Header

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
  from("timer:hello?repeatCount=1")
            .setProperty("someDateField",constant(new Date()))
            .log("${date:exchangeProperty.someDateField:yyyy/MM/dd}");
```

Comment: Can we avoid using the `java.util.Date` class? It is poorly designed and long outdated. I would much rather use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: camel dsl doesnt support LocalDateTime.  you can create a bean and you can assign to a property new formatted value

Comment: maybe you can use simple for this  body has some value which type LocalDateTime and locale date time has format method
.setProperty("format",consntant(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME))
simple("${body.format(exchangeProperty.format)} ")